# If we use netem for delay in network, why downloading file with lesser size

Tags: networking

I am using the following commands for adding delay using `netem` then downloading a file from web using `wget` command. When I download the file without delay its something like `226k` with `0.09s`(time taken for download) but when I added delay of `100ms`, now again downloading the same file from same destination but this time I am getting file size as `105k` with `0.2s`. I am getting delay as expected but why I am getting file with lesser size?

Command for adding delay:-

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms
```

Command to download file:-

```
wget -P . https://www.excentis.com/sites/excentis/files/styles/full-width/public/linux_tc_configs.png 2>&1 | tee -a wget_log
```

Logs After adding adding delay:-

```
--2018-03-27 08:58:50--              
https://www.excentis.com/sites/excentis/files/styles/full-width/public/linux_tc_configs.png
Resolving www.excentis.com (www.excentis.com)... IP_address
Connecting to www.excentis.com (www.excentis.com)|IP_address|:<PORT>... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 20016 (20K) [image/png]
Saving to: ‘./linux_tc_configs.png.3’

 0K .......... .........                                  100%  226K=0.09s

2018-03-27 08:58:51 (226 KB/s) - ‘./linux_tc_configs.png.3’ saved [20016/20016]
```

Logs After adding adding delay:-

```
--2018-03-27 08:58:23--  
https://www.excentis.com/sites/excentis/files/styles/full-width/public/linux_tc_configs.png
Resolving www.excentis.com (www.excentis.com)... IP_address
Connecting to www.excentis.com (www.excentis.com)|IP_address|:<PORT>... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 20016 (20K) [image/png]
Saving to: ‘./linux_tc_configs.png.2’

 0K .......... .........                                  100%  105K=0.2s

2018-03-27 08:58:24 (105 KB/s) - ‘./linux_tc_configs.png.2’ saved [20016/20016]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File size compression will not happen when you use netem suit. File is not compressed or changed anywhere when you download using the command you have used, so file size remains the same. Referring your verbose output,

```
> --2018-03-27 08:58:50--               https://www.excentis.com/sites/excentis/files/styles/full-width/public/linux_tc_configs.png
> Resolving www.excentis.com (www.excentis.com)... IP_address Connecting
> to www.excentis.com (www.excentis.com)|IP_address|:<PORT>...
> connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length:
> **20016 (20K)** [image/png] Saving to: ‘./linux_tc_configs.png.3’
> 
>  0K .......... .........                                  100% 
> 226K=0.09s
> 
> 2018-03-27 08:58:51 (226 KB/s) - ‘./linux_tc_configs.png.3’ saved
> [20016/20016]
```

File size of that png image is mentioned in the 5th line of your output - 20K.

226K=0.09s  mentioned in the log tells that the throughput was 226 KB/s and it took 0.09s to download you 20K file.

If you need to check that you can use the following command.

```
wget --progress=bar:force -P . https://www.excentis.com/sites/excentis/files/styles/full-width/public/linux_tc_configs.png 2>&1 | tee -a wget_log
```

```
   Resolving www.excentis.com (www.excentis.com)... 77.235.46.234
Connecting to www.excentis.com (www.excentis.com)|77.235.46.234|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 20016 (20K) [image/png]
Saving to: ‘./linux_tc_configs.png.6’

100%[======================================>] 20,016      74.3KB/s   in 0.3s

2018-03-27 05:47:19 (74.3 KB/s) - ‘./linux_tc_configs.png.6’ saved [20016/20016]
```